# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) after reinstalling mySQL twice

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-2002

[Login attempts and Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ34B.png)

I have included an image which shows all the login attempts i made including -h localhost and -h 127.0.0.1.

I have even checked for space issues and haven't had any issues regarding that.

I was able to access the databases 2 days ago and today it's giving me this error.

I have seen the purge and reinstall would solve this issue and have already done that to previously run mySQL and wouldn't want to do that every time i have that issue.

Please look into the errors i am getting and suggest a way to tackle it.

I am open to provide more additional data if requested or as required.

Thanks in advance.

This is what i found in var/log/mysql/error.log

```
2018-06-12T13:59:38.147016Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-06-12T13:59:38.507148Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2018-06-12T13:59:38.579416Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2018-06-12T13:59:38.647136Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: d8a93ee9-6e48-11e8-b5af-32306b28cd52.
2018-06-12T13:59:38.648977Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2018-06-12T13:59:38.650160Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
```

Comment: Why don't you share the error messages in text form?

Comment: Have you had a look at MySQL's own log files?

Comment: Does the folder `/var/run/mysqld/` exist and is writable by the mysqld process? What happens when you simply try to start `mysqld`, what is in `/var/log/mysql*`, what is in `/var/log/syslog` ? One thing for sure, you can reinstall 10000 times if you don't fix the error itself it's useless.